# Error getting on parsing json data with getting positions in listview

Tags: java, sharedpreferences

This is my MainClass where I am showing the Listview as a Surah List

```
package com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformingprayers.R;
import com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.PojoQuran.SharedSurahPref;
import com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.QuranData.Surah;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class QuranVersions extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> SurahList;
    ListView SurahListName;
    TextView Ayah;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quran_versions);
        Ayah = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ayah);

        prepareDate();
        SurahListName = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.quranAyahList);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> surahLists = new ArrayAdapter<String>(QuranVersions.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,SurahList);
        SurahListName.setAdapter(surahLists);
        SurahListName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(QuranVersions.this, Surah.class).putExtra("index",position));
            }
        });
    }


    private void prepareDate(){
        SurahList = new ArrayList<>();

        SurahList.add("1 Surah Al-Fatihah");
        SurahList.add("2 Surah Al-Baqara");
        SurahList.add("3 Surah Al-i'Imran");
        SurahList.add("4 Surah An-Nisaa");
        SurahList.add("5 Surah Al-Maidah");
        SurahList.add("6 Surah Al-An'am");
        SurahList.add("7 Surah Al-A'raf");
        SurahList.add("8 Surah Al-Anfal");
        SurahList.add("9 Surah At-Tauba");
        SurahList.add("10 Surah Yunus");
        SurahList.add("11 Surah Hud");
        SurahList.add("12 Surah Yusuf");
        SurahList.add("13 Surah Ar-Ra'd");
        SurahList.add("14 Surah Ibrahim");
        SurahList.add("15 Surah Al-Hijr");
        SurahList.add("16 Surah An-Nahl");
        SurahList.add("17 Surah Al-Israa");
        SurahList.add("18 Surah Al-Kahf");
        SurahList.add("19 Surah Maryam");
        SurahList.add("20 Surah Ta-ha");
        SurahList.add("21 Surah Al-Anbiyaa");
        SurahList.add("22 Surah Al-Hajj");
        SurahList.add("23 Surah Al-Muminun");
        SurahList.add("24 Surah An-Nur");
        SurahList.add("25 Surah Al-Furqan");
        SurahList.add("26 Surah Ash-Shu'araa");
        SurahList.add("27 Surah An-Naml");
        SurahList.add("28 Surah Al-Qasas");
        SurahList.add("29 Surah Al-Ankabut");
        SurahList.add("30 Surah Ar-Rum");
        SurahList.add("31 Surah Luqman");
        SurahList.add("32 Surah As-Sajda");
        SurahList.add("33 Surah Al-Ahzab");
        SurahList.add("34 Surah Saba");
        SurahList.add("35 Surah Fatir");
        SurahList.add("36 Surah Ya-Sin");
        SurahList.add("37 Surah As-Saffat");
        SurahList.add("38 Surah Sad");
        SurahList.add("39 Surah Az-Zumar");
        SurahList.add("40 Surah Al-Mu'min");
        SurahList.add("41 Surah Ha-Mim");
        SurahList.add("42 Surah Ash-Shura");
        SurahList.add("43 Surah Az-Zukhruf");
        SurahList.add("44 Surah Ad-Dukhan");
        SurahList.add("45 Surah Al-Jathiya");
        SurahList.add("46 Surah Al-Ahqaf");
        SurahList.add("47 Surah Muhammad");
        SurahList.add("48 Surah Al-Fat-h");
        SurahList.add("49 Surah Al-Hujurat");
        SurahList.add("50 Surah Qaf");
        SurahList.add("51 Surah Az-Zariyat");
        SurahList.add("52 Surah At-Tur");
        SurahList.add("53 Surah An-Najm");
        SurahList.add("54 Surah Al-Qamar");
        SurahList.add("55 Surah Ar-Rahman");
        SurahList.add("56 Surah Al-Waqi'a");
        SurahList.add("57 Surah Al-Hadid");
        SurahList.add("58 Surah Al-Mujadila");
        SurahList.add("59 Surah Al-Hashr");
        SurahList.add("60 Surah Al-Mumtahana");
        SurahList.add("61 Surah As-Saff");
        SurahList.add("62 Surah Al-Jumu'a");
        SurahList.add("63 Surah Al-Munafiqun");
        SurahList.add("64 Surah At-Tagabun");
        SurahList.add("65 Surah At-Talaq");
        SurahList.add("66 Surah At-Tahrim");
        SurahList.add("67 Surah Al-Mulk");
        SurahList.add("68 Surah Al-Qalam");
        SurahList.add("69 Surah Al-Haqqa");
        SurahList.add("70 Surah Al-Ma'arij");
        SurahList.add("71 Surah Nuh");
        SurahList.add("72 Surah Al-Jinn");
        SurahList.add("73 Surah Al-Muzzammil");
        SurahList.add("74 Surah Al-Muddathth");
        SurahList.add("75 Surah Al-Qiyamat");
        SurahList.add("76 Surah Ad-Dahr");
        SurahList.add("77 Surah Al-Mursalat");
        SurahList.add("78 Surah An-Nabaa");
        SurahList.add("79 Surah An-Nazi'at");
        SurahList.add("80 Surah Abasa");
        SurahList.add("81 Surah At-Takwir");
        SurahList.add("82 Surah Al-Infitar");
        SurahList.add("83 Surah Al-Mutaffifin");
        SurahList.add("84 Surah Al-Inshiqaq");
        SurahList.add("85 Surah Al-Buruj");
        SurahList.add("86 Surah At-Tariq");
        SurahList.add("87 Surah Al-A'la");
        SurahList.add("88 Surah Al-Gashiya");
        SurahList.add("89 Surah Al-Fajr");
        SurahList.add("90 Surah Al-Balad");
        SurahList.add("91 Surah Ash-Shams");
        SurahList.add("92 Surah Al-Lail");
        SurahList.add("93 Surah Adh-Dhuha");
        SurahList.add("94 Surah Al-Sharh");
        SurahList.add("95 Surah At-Tin");
        SurahList.add("96 Surah Al-Alaq");
        SurahList.add("97 Surah Al-Qadr");
        SurahList.add("98 Surah Al-Baiyina");
        SurahList.add("99 Surah Al-Zalzalah");
        SurahList.add("100 Surah Al-Adiyat");
        SurahList.add("101 Surah Al-Qari'a");
        SurahList.add("102 Surah At-Takathur");
        SurahList.add("103 Surah Al-Asr");
        SurahList.add("104 Surah Al-Humaza");
        SurahList.add("105 Surah Al-Fil");
        SurahList.add("106 Surah Quraish");
        SurahList.add("107 Surah Al-Ma'un");
        SurahList.add("108 Surah Al-Kauthar");
        SurahList.add("109 Surah Al-Kafirun");
        SurahList.add("110 Surah An-Nasr");
        SurahList.add("111 Surah Al-Lahab");
        SurahList.add("112 Surah Al-Ikhlas");
        SurahList.add("113 Surah Al-Falaq");
        SurahList.add("114 Surah Al-Nas");
    }

    // Read the company.json file and convert it to a java object.



}
```

This is my XML file of this class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10sp"
    tools:context="com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.QuranVersions">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/ayah"
        android:text=""/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/quranAyahList"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Surah file where I am parsing json data

Surah.Java

```
package com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.QuranData;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformingprayers.R;
import com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.PojoQuran.SharedSurahPref;
import com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.PojoQuran.SurahResponse;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class Surah extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView AyatDetail;
    List<String> ayatLDetail;

    TextView totalAyat, surahNum, surahName;
    int selectedSurrahIndex = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_surah);
        selectedSurrahIndex = getIntent().getIntExtra("index",0);
        generateSurahData(selectedSurrahIndex);
        setUpUiView();

        final ArrayAdapter<String> ayatList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Surah.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ayatLDetail);
        AyatDetail.setAdapter(ayatList);
    }


    private void setUpUiView(){
        totalAyat = findViewById(R.id.totalAyah);
        surahNum  = findViewById(R.id.surahNo);
        surahName = findViewById(R.id.surahName);
        AyatDetail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.AyatDetail);
    }

    private void generateSurahData(int surrahIndex)
    {
        if(!SharedSurahPref.allSurah.containsKey(surrahIndex))
        {
            InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(SharedSurahPref.SurrahNames.get(surrahIndex));
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int ctr;
            try {
                ctr = inputStream.read();
                while (ctr != -1) {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(ctr);
                    ctr = inputStream.read();
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.v("Text Data", byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
            try
            {
                // Parse the data into json object to get original data in form of json.
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());
                SurahResponse model = new Gson().fromJson(jObject.toString(), SurahResponse.class);
                SharedSurahPref.allSurah.put(surrahIndex, model);

                if (SharedSurahPref.allSurah.size() > surrahIndex) {
                    totalAyat.setText(SharedSurahPref.allSurah.get(surrahIndex).getTotalAyah());
                    surahNum.setText(SharedSurahPref.allSurah.get(surrahIndex).getSurahNo()+"");
                    totalAyat.setText(SharedSurahPref.allSurah.get(surrahIndex).getTotalAyah()+"");

                    ayatLDetail.add(SharedSurahPref.detailHashMap.get(surrahIndex).getArbi());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XML file of Surah.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.QuranData.Surah">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/totalAyah"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/surahNo"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/surahName"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ayatNum"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/AyatDetail"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the SharefSurahPref.class where all the json files are parsing to the surah activity

```
package com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.PojoQuran;

import android.view.View;

import com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformingprayers.R;
import com.google.android.gms.flags.impl.SharedPreferencesFactory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SharedSurahPref extends SharedPreferencesFactory {


    public static ArrayList<Integer> SurrahNames = new ArrayList<>();
    public static HashMap<Integer,SurahResponse> allSurah = new HashMap<>();
    public static HashMap<String, AyatDetail> detailHashMap = new HashMap();


    SharedSurahPref(){
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_fateh_1);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_bakra_2);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_imran_3);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_nisa_4);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_maida_5);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_inaam_6);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_araaf_7);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_infaal_8);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_tobah_9);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_younus_10);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_hud_11);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_yousaf_12);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_radd_13);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ibrahim_14);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_hijar_15);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_nahal_16);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_isra_17);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_kahf_18);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_maryam_19);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_taha_20);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ambiyaa_21);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_hajj_22);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_muminun_23);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_noor_24);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_furqaan_25);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_shaer_26);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_naml_27);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_qasas_28);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ankabut_29);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_rom_30);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_luqman_31);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_sajda_32);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ahzaab_33);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_saba_34);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_fatir_35);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_yasin_36);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_saffat_37);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_sad_38);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_zamar_39);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ghafir_40);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_faslat_41);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_shuara_42);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_zakhruf_43);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_dakhan_44);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_jasiya_45);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ahkaf_46);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_muhammad_47);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_fatah_48);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_hajrat_49);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_qaf_50);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_zariyat_51);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_toor_52);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_najam_53);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_qamar_54);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ar_rehman_55);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_waqiah_56);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_hadid_57);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mujadillah_58);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_hashar_59);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mumtahina_60);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_saf_61);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_jummah_62);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_munafiqun_63);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_taghabun_64);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_talaq_65);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_tehrim_66);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mulk_67);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_qalam_68);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_haqah_69);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_meeraj_70);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_noah_71);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_jinn_72);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_muzamil_73);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mudasir_74);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_qiyamah_75);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_insan_76);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mursalat_77);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_naba_78);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_naziat_79);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_abas_80);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_at_takwir_81);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_infitar_82);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mutaffifin_83);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_inshiqaq_84);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_buruj_85);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_at_tariq_86);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_aala_87);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_ghashiyah_88);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_fajr_89);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_balad_90);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ash_shams_91);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_lail_92);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ad_duha_93);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_an_nashrah_94);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_at_teen_95);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_alaq_96);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_qadr_97);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_bayyinah_98);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_zilzali_99);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_adiyaat_100);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_quriah_101);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_at_takasur_102);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_asr_103);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_humazah_104);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_feel_105);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_quraish_106);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_maoon_107);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_kausar_108);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_kafirun_109);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_an_nasr_110);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_tabbat_111);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_ikhlas_112);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_falaq_113);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_an_naas_114);
    }
}
```

This is the Ayat Verses getter and setters

```
package com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.PojoQuran;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class AyatDetail extends SurahResponse {

    @SerializedName("ayet_no")
    @Expose
    private Integer ayetNo;
    @SerializedName("arbi")
    @Expose
    private String arbi;
    @SerializedName("Urdu")
    @Expose
    private String urdu;
    @SerializedName("English")
    @Expose
    private String english;

    public Integer getAyetNo() {
        return ayetNo;
    }

    public void setAyetNo(Integer ayetNo) {
        this.ayetNo = ayetNo;
    }

    public String getArbi() {
        return arbi;
    }

    public void setArbi(String arbi) {
        this.arbi = arbi;
    }

    public String getUrdu() {
        return urdu;
    }

    public void setUrdu(String urdu) {
        this.urdu = urdu;
    }

    public String getEnglish() {
        return english;
    }

    public void setEnglish(String english) {
        this.english = english;
    }
}
```

This is the surah no and surah name getter setter class

```
package com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.PojoQuran;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SurahResponse {

    @SerializedName("surah_no")
    @Expose
    private Integer surahNo;
    @SerializedName("total_ayah")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalAyah;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("detail")
    @Expose
    private List<AyatDetail> detail = null;

    public Integer getSurahNo() {
        return surahNo;
    }

    public void setSurahNo(Integer surahNo) {
        this.surahNo = surahNo;
    }

    public Integer getTotalAyah() {
        return totalAyah;
    }

    public void setTotalAyah(Integer totalAyah) {
        this.totalAyah = totalAyah;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<AyatDetail> getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(List<AyatDetail> detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

}
```

When i click on the first index in listview the logcat gives an error of included below

```
Process: com.example.osamasaleem.prayertimes, PID: 31057
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.osamasaleem.prayertimes/com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.QuranData.Surah}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1895)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1589)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4234)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4192)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4535)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4503)
        at com.example.prayertimes.timetoperformprayers.QuranVersions$1.onItemClick(QuranVersions.java:42)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:315)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1210)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3349)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$4.run(AbsListView.java:4410)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6339)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:945)
```

This is my 41 line number

```
SurahListName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(QuranVersions.this, Surah.class).putExtra("index",position));
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I fix this Logcat error?

Comment: Great, thanks. Also, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this site :)

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in QuranVersions.java (That is the SurahList in Above Question)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quran_versions);
        Ayah = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ayah);

        prepareDate();
        SurahListName = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.quranAyahList);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> surahLists = new ArrayAdapter<String>(QuranVersions.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,SurahList);
        SurahListName.setAdapter(surahLists);
        SurahListName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              startActivity(new Intent(QuranVersions.this, Surah.class).putExtra("index", position+""));
                //startActivity(new Intent(QuranVersions.this, Surah.class).putExtra("index",position));
            }
        });
    }
```

And In SharedSurahPref.java just created a static function

```
   public static void initialization(){
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_fateh_1);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_bakra_2);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_imran_3);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_nisa_4);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_maida_5);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_inaam_6);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_araaf_7);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_infaal_8);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_tobah_9);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_younus_10);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_hud_11);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_yousaf_12);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_radd_13);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ibrahim_14);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_hijar_15);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_nahal_16);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_isra_17);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_kahf_18);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_maryam_19);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_taha_20);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ambiyaa_21);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_hajj_22);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_muminun_23);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_noor_24);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_furqaan_25);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_shaer_26);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_naml_27);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_qasas_28);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ankabut_29);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_rom_30);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_luqman_31);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_sajda_32);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ahzaab_33);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_saba_34);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_fatir_35);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_yasin_36);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_saffat_37);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_sad_38);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_zamar_39);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ghafir_40);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_faslat_41);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_shuara_42);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_zakhruf_43);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_dakhan_44);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_jasiya_45);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ahkaf_46);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_muhammad_47);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_fatah_48);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_hajrat_49);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_qaf_50);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_zariyat_51);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_toor_52);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_najam_53);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_qamar_54);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ar_rehman_55);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_waqiah_56);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_hadid_57);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mujadillah_58);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_hashar_59);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mumtahina_60);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_saf_61);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_jummah_62);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_munafiqun_63);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_taghabun_64);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_talaq_65);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_tehrim_66);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mulk_67);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_qalam_68);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_haqah_69);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_meeraj_70);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_noah_71);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_jinn_72);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_muzamil_73);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mudasir_74);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_qiyamah_75);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_insan_76);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mursalat_77);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_naba_78);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_naziat_79);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_abas_80);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_at_takwir_81);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_infitar_82);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_mutaffifin_83);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_inshiqaq_84);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_buruj_85);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_at_tariq_86);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_aala_87);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_ghashiyah_88);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_fajr_89);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_balad_90);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ash_shams_91);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_lail_92);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_ad_duha_93);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_an_nashrah_94);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_at_teen_95);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_alaq_96);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_qadr_97);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_bayyinah_98);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_zilzali_99);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_adiyaat_100);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_quriah_101);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_at_takasur_102);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_asr_103);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_humazah_104);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_feel_105);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_quraish_106);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_maoon_107);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_kausar_108);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_kafirun_109);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_an_nasr_110);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_tabbat_111);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_ikhlas_112);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_al_falaq_113);
        SurrahNames.add(R.raw.surah_e_an_naas_114);
    }
```

And called this function inside the launcher activity in manifest

```
   SharedSurahPref.initialization();
```

This is how i resolved this but i'm still not getting the json data in text view and its actually not picking up the json data it getting null